# Redraw objects on another UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, coordinates

I have two circle objects on main view with coordinates: first.frame 100,100,20,20 and second 200,200,20,20
Main view frame is 0,0,320,480

I want to create another view with frame 50,50,200,200 and add my circles to that view, but that the new position was the same in relation to the main view

If I use this code I have:

```
...
    [self.view addSubview:anotherView];

    for (CircleView *circle in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([circle isKindOfClass:[CircleView class]])
                [anotherView addSubview:circle];
    }
```

My circles is replace to another view, but coordinates is same like a left-up corner not main view, another view

How to replace my objects to another view with same coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use convertPoint:fromView: or convertPoint:toView: something like this:

```
CGRect newCircleFrame = circle.frame;
newCircleFrame.origin = [self.view convertPoint: circle.frame.orign
                                         toView: anotherView];
```